# How can I put an icon in a MudNavLink that will show up correctly at the end of the link?

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

How can I put an icon in a `MudNavLink` that will show up correctly at the end of the link? It looks like the API currently only supports icons at the front, and manually adding a `MudIcon` does not style correctly.

[image: example]

```
<MudNavMenu>
    <MudNavLink Href="#" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.OpenInNew">Correct placement on left</MudNavLink>
    <MudNavLink Href="#"><MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.OpenInNew" /> Incorrect placement on left</MudNavLink>
    <MudNavLink Href="#">Correct placement on right <MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.OpenInNew" /></MudNavLink>
</MudNavMenu>
```

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GuQHYTwGqQgUbeXG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [CSS utilities](https://mudblazor.com/utilities/position#class-reference) that are available.

```
<MudNavLink Href="#">absolute
  <MudIcon Class="absolute" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.OpenInNew" />
</MudNavLink>
```

[Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QOmdOfmUqzTYUqwr)

Answer (score 0):

I could not get a `NavLink` to work either, might be possible with some css hacks but I didnt bother. Certainly not ideal but you could use a `Button`:

```
<MudButton Variant="Variant.Text" EndIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.OpenInNew" Color="Color.Default" Style="text-transform: none;">Correct placement on right</MudButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

A desperate way is to take fully control of the content in NavLink. Like this:

```
    <MudNavLink Href="@($"/AdaPPM/Reports/OrganizationReports")">
        <div @onclick="@((e) => UiGlobal.CloseNavMenu())" class="ml-n3 pr-4">
            <MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Material.Outlined.Article" Class="mr-3" Style="margin-bottom: -6px;"></MudIcon>Text here
        </div>
    </MudNavLink>
```

It works like a normal nav link plus you can do anything else if you want.